# Image map plugin not working with point data QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a point shapefile and I am trying to create a html image from it using the html image map plugin; however, I can not get it work.

I get the error:

```
Wrong geometry type
```

Any ideas on this?

Also, can you zoom into the layer and render the layer, i.e. have labels turning on at a certain scale. Seems a useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

I only get that error message if a line layer is active.

You can have all kinds of layers in your canvas (even openlayers plugin background), but the one active (which will generate links and mouse-hover messages) must be of type polygon or point.

You get only the screen resolution, zooming in is not intended with the plugin's output.